# Linked list, add node to end

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I'm working on a project and I was given this function to complete

```
void addToEnd(node*& head, string newVal)

Effect:  adds new node to tail end of list 
Precondition: head is a pointer to first node in the list (list MAY be empty)
Postcondition: list contains one more node
```

***My question is what is the string newVal for?***

The value_type of this class is of type DOUBLE so I'm confused what string newVal is for. So I can't set the newVal in the node because it is of two different types.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure if im going in the right direction.

```
node *temp = new node;
temp = head;

while(temp->link() != NULL){
    temp = temp->link();
}

head->set_link(temp);
```

I'm not even sure where to use the string in this block of code.

`link()` returns the member variable `node* link_field`
`set_link()` sets the new link to the `link_field`

Comment: When you add a new node, set that new node's value to stringval. Also I don't think you specified what link and set link do

Comment: _"The value_type of this class is of type DOUBLE"_ Check what can actually be done about [converting `std::string` to `double()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: Wow, that's a really badly done specification. You're expected to just guess what role `newVal` should have had in the precondition and there's no mention in the postcondition that `node` may be changed (I guess you're supposed to infer that from the fact that it's a reference to pointer).

Comment: Since the string is not mentioned in the requirements, you can probably ignore it. Or maybe it's just to make you go back to whoever created the problem and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we're guessing that they somehow expect you to turn a string into a double with a function like [`std::stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/).

As for your list manipulation code, there's a few problems:

```
node *temp = new node;
temp = head;
```

This creates a new node, puts its pointer in `temp`, then immediately overwrites `temp` with `head`, losing (leaking) the new node. Don't do that.

```
while(temp->link() != NULL){
    temp = temp->link();
}
```

This is close, but might not work. The problem is that you need to keep track of the real node pointer, not a copy.

Normally, in a linked list API using pointers instead of references, the "add node" function looks like:

```
void addToEnd(node** head, string newVal)
{
    while(*head)
        head = &((*head)->next);
    *head = new node;
    (*head)->value = newVal;
    (*head)->next = 0;
}
```

Note that if the list is empty, the passed-in head pointer is altered to point to the new node. If the list is not empty, the last `next` pointer is altered instead.

The API you're given (i.e. the `link` and `set_link` methods) doesn't allow this, because the head pointer is not a `node` and those functions require a `node`. So you've got to do it a little differently, namely you have to handle the empty list case separately.

```
void addToEnd(node*& head, string newVal)
{
    // Create the node.
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->value = std::stod(newVal);
    newNode->set_link(0);

    if(!head) // Empty list?
    {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // Find last node.
    node* item = head;
    while(item->link())
        item = item->link();
    item->set_link(newNode);
}
```

Comment: newNode->set_link(0); the 0 here would be the same as NULL?

Comment: Yep. I'm an old-school C++ guy, so I use `0` to represent null pointers. (`NULL` is really a C thing, and it was discouraged for a while in C++ because it was usually a `#define` macro so it couldn't go in the `std` namespace, among several other reasons.) The proper way to do it in C++11 and later is to use `nullptr` since it's got better type safety than either `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: cool thank you! There's a little issue I just ran into with the cod e and my compiler. node* item = &head; I got an error saying "cannot convert node** to node* in intialization"

Comment: Use node* item = head;

Comment: I thought we didn't want to do that because of (leaking)? As stated above. But yes it will work if I do that.

Comment: @Learner: Fixed. @WhatThePhil: In my code, the line after `// Find last node.` was `node* item = &head;` which won't compile because `&head` is of type `node**`. The `&` was leftover from the prior version of the function.